# Variable indefinida después de redireccionar

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo los siguientes 3 archivos: `inicio.php`, `Informe.php` y `plano.php`

en el archivo `inicio.php` tengo un select con un botón que al presionarlo me enviara a `Informe.php`, este es el codigo:

```
<form class="" action="Informe.php" method="post">
  <p>Selecciona el periodo</p>
  <select class="" name="periodo">
    <?php
      WHILE($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
      {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo substr($row[0], -6, -2)."/".substr($row[0], 4); ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Ejecutar"></input>
</form>
```

creo que no es necesario colocar la conexión o consulta que hago, el select me contiene unos valores que llamo periodo que uso en este formato:
`201809` (año y mes).

en el archivo `Informe.php` tengo lo siguiente:

```
$var11 = $_POST["periodo"];

<h2 class="araryP right-tittle ">Periodo: <?php echo substr($var11, -6, -2)."/". substr($var11+"1", 4); ?></h2>
```

lo que hago en el h2 es mostrar el periodo separando el mes del día por ejemplo el periodo `201809` se mostrara como `2018/09`

y esto funciona normal, ahora tengo un botón que me lleva al archivo `plano.php`

lo que hago en `plano.php` es básicamente nada por el momento, estaba probando la redireccion y la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">
window.location.href="Informe.php";
</script>';
```

este código me redirecciona bien al archivo `Informe.php` pero cuando me redirije me dice que la variable `periodo` no esta definida, la variable periodo es la que envió desde `inicio.php` a `Informe.php`

¿Que puedo hacer para que la variable mantenga su valor?

Comment: Muestra el error que te da para poderte ayudar.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: periodo in C:\xampp\htdocs\plano\Informe.php on line 22` como dije, solo me dice que no esta definida

Comment: declaraste `$var1` pero usas `$var11` en Informe.php

Comment: si fue un error que cometí, en realidad ambas son $var11

Comment: **En resumen**: envías el `$_POST["periodo"];`de `inicio.php` a `Informe.php`. después vas a `plano.php` pero ya has perdido el $_POST. Ahora que ya no tienes el $_POST vuelves a `inicio.php` . Es esto?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que verificar que la variable exista

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["periodo"]):?>
     <? $var11 = $_POST["periodo"]; ?>
     <h2 class="araryP right-tittle ">Periodo: <?php echo substr($var11, -6, -2)."/". substr($var11+"1", 4); ?></h2>
<?php endif ?>
```

Dale una leída a esa función nativa de PHP
http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php

PARA CONSERVAR LA VARIABLE HAZ LO SIGUIENTE

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["periodo"]) {
     $_SESSION["periodo"] = $POST["periodo"];
} ?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["periodo"))?>
     <? $var11 = $_SESSION["periodo"]; ?>
     <h2 class="araryP right-tittle ">Periodo: <?php echo substr($var11, -6, -2)."/". substr($var11+"1", 4); ?></h2>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Pero eso no resuelve mi problema, necesito que la variable conserve su valor

Comment: Las variables no se guardan, una vez que cambias de archivo se reinician, si la quieres conservar entonces guardala en una variable de sesión

Comment: he agregado en la edición como podría quedar con variables de sesión

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto en el archivo `Informe.php`

```
 if($_POST["periodo"] == TRUE)
    {
       $var1 = $_POST["periodo"];

<?php 
  <h2 class="araryP right-tittle ">Periodo: <?php echo substr($var11, -6, -2)."/". substr($var11+"1", 4); ?></h2>
?>

    }else{

      <?php 
  <h2 class="araryP right-tittle ">Periodo:</h2>
?>
    }
```

Comment: pero como muestro los `h2`? asi como pusiste no se puede

Comment: Listo, Tienes que abrir y cerrar las etiquetas PHP para poder escribir código HTML.

Comment: me sigue saliendo el mismo error, la variable no esta definida, pero lo que en realidad necesito es que la variable mantenga su valor, tu código hace que si no esta definida no la muestra y ya